# Make Cytoscape.js container just wide enough and just long enough

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cytoscape.js

I am rendering several tree layouts in separate canvases using [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/).

Currently, each canvas is enveloped by a container div with set dimensions (e.g. 400x400). Cytoscape offers a setting to fit each tree into its container, and will zoom in an out of each tree to the extent necessary to make the full tree visible within the given dimensions.

Instead of telling each layout to fit the container, I would like to instead resize each container to accommodate its child canvas perfectly. In other words, I need a way of asking each instance of the Cytoscape canvas, "What width and height would you be at 0 zoom", or "how many pixels do you need in each direction to draw fully", and then resize each container appropriately.

Cytoscape does offer methods to get the canvas's [`width()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.width) and [`height()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.height), but those end up being the actual dimensions (which may not fit the container), instead of the "desired"/needed dimensions.

It occurred to me that I could come up with some heuristic to set the container's width and height based on the number of nodes and edges, but this approach hasn't proven fruitful yet; the number of nodes and edges tells me little about the final layout and arrangement, which alone informs decisions about desired width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
eles.boundingBox(options);
```

or:

```
eles.renderedBoundingBox();
```

'eles' has to be this:

```
var eles = cy.elements();
```

You can get two information about your nodes via the cytoscape methods mostly:
The actual position in cytoscape and it's rendered position, read this article for more information:

http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position

To your second question:

Aligning your tree is quite easy if you just call

```
cy.fit(/*eles, padding*/); // Pan and zoom fitted to the tree
cy.center(/*eles*/); // Moves the graph to the exact center of your tree
cy.elements().shift('x', offset); // Moves the nodes to the right, offset must be negative to move them to the left
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. What's interesting is that it doesn't align the tree all the way to the left - in some cases there are margins of up to 100px to the left of the tree - which still leads to the rest of the tree on the right being covered up.

I mitigate this by calling `cy.fit()` - this seems clunky, however, especially given that it requires an arbitrary timeout, even if called in the layout's `ready` callback. Is there a better way to align the entire tree to the canvas's left egde?

Comment: I added the answer above, please let me know if this helped :)

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but are you sure it aligns trees to the left? It sounds like it would align them to the center, and it's doing that already.

Comment: Oh you are right... i edited the answer, you need to find out how big offset has to be to move the graph to the right position.

Comment: You have the bounding box of the graph and the width of cytoscape, subtract the width from the box and divide by two, there you have your offset :)

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the right answer as it gave you the solution to the original post? <3